# How do I get heroku to honor module support?

Tags: node.js, heroku, knex.js

I have an express server with knex migrations using ES modules. All my file extensions are `.js`.

I can run migrations successfully: `yarn run knex migrate:latest --env development`.

When I try to run migrations using heroku cli: `heroku run knex migrate:latest`, I get this error:

```
require() of ES Module /app/knexfile.js from /app/node_modules/knex/lib/migrations/util/import-file.js not supported.
Instead change the require of knexfile.js in /app/node_modules/knex/lib/migrations/util/import-file.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /app/knexfile.js from /app/node_modules/knex/lib/migrations/util/import-file.js not supported.
```

My `yarn.lock` file is checked in and up-to-date.
My `package.json` file specifies versions as requested:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x",
    "npm": "8.x",
    "yarn": "1.x"
  },
  "type": "module",
```

How do I get heroku to honor module support?

Answer (score 0):

Knex `0.95.x` checks `process.env.npm_package_type==='module'` to determine if the imported file is a CommonJs or ES module.

That variable doesn't get set in the heroku nodejs buildpack environment with the specified version of yarn. I added this to the heroku config variables to solve this problem.